# Windows CE Async .Net webservice call results in empty callback object

Tags: vb.net, web-services, oop, windows-ce

I'm stuck... :)

Windows CE (.Net Compact Framework 3.5) code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Data

Imports windowscetest.aliweb

Public Class main

    Const url = "http://myip/asw/services.asmx"

    Const ip = "x.x.x.x"
    Const uid = "USERID"
    Const pwd = "PASSWORD"
    Const bib = "LIBRARY"

    Dim screen As New ScreenEngine
    Dim service As New services

    Dim r As New Result

    Private Sub main_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        screen = New ScreenEngine
        screen.SetFullScreen(True)

        If IsAlive() Then

            With service
                .Url = url
                .connectionValue = New connection

                With .connectionValue
                    .Server = ip
                    .User = uid
                    .Password = pwd
                    .Library = bib
                End With

                .PreAuthenticate = True
                .Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

                .BeginExecute("select * from z2ooprxt where renum like '1396%'", Operation.SelectMultipleRows, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Ended), r)

            End With

        Else

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub main_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
        screen.SetFullScreen(False)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Ended(ByVal e As System.IAsyncResult)



    End Sub

    Private Function IsAlive() As Boolean

        Dim rq As HttpWebRequest
        Dim rs As HttpWebResponse

        Try

            rq = WebRequest.Create(url)
            rs = rq.GetResponse

            If Not rs.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                Return False
            End If

            rs.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

        Return True

    End Function

End Class
```

Web service answers with OOP object `Result` holding different things including a Datatable.

It appears that `e` from `Ended` is empty...
If I call the webservice **synchronously** everything works ok.
I believe it has something to do with a stateobject but I can't seem to find
any examples...

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an async method, you need to invoke EndExecute to get the result, like this:

```
Private Sub Ended(ByVal e As System.IAsyncResult)

    service.EndExecute(e)  ' This will give you the result

End Sub
```